# Can I put a variable in my dot source in powershell

Tags: powershell

Dumb question, I was wondering if I am able to put a variable in my dot source when pulling in a function. I have a couple of scripts that I add to others to ensure that I have common variables and so forth.  but I always assume someone is going to put them in the C directory.  How can I make sure if they put them in F: or D powershell will still be able to find them?  For example...

```
. C:\CI\scripts\variables.ps1

Function StopOrStartServices{    
    Param
    (
        $ServiceName,     
        $Remoteserver,
        $StopOrStart
    )
```

If I change the above lines to the following...

```
Function StopOrStartServices{    
    Param
    (
        $ServiceName,     
        $Remoteserver,
        $StopOrStart
        $baseDir
    )

. $baseDir\CI\scripts\variables.ps1
```

Will that still work?

From my understanding, you have to have your dot source as one of the first lines in your script?  Or am I confusing that with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Powershell will expand that variable for you before calling the .ps1 script.  The only restriction I can think of that is similar to what you are referring to is the need to import scripts before using the contents of them.

Since PS is an interpreted (not compiled) language it gets run from the top down, and you need to import any includes or modules before invoking them.

Comment: Besides missing a comma in your param list, yes it should work fine.  Pretty much anything in PS can be expanded. I use that same method in a lot of my own scripts.

Comment: Thanks much for the wisdom and knowledge my friend.